# Vue-Router isn't working in production - Vue3

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vue-router, production

My router is working fine on localhost but once I built the project the app bar disappeared and the routers stopped working.
[image: 1]

[image: AppBar]

As the last image shows how app bar isn't working on production in the first image

Comment: It says "Cannot read property of undefined", `$router` is just the property that is accessed. So it probably isn't the router, but whatever should hold it. Do you know which line causes the error?

Comment: I fixed it, but router still not working

Comment: When I try to navigate using buttons it gives me this error
```Error: Loading CSS chunk 443 failed.
(http://localhost:3000/css/about.0add0516.css)
    at HTMLLinkElement.i (css loading:15:14)
Q @ vue-router.mjs:3451
(anonym```